# Devise authentication using another field instead of using email field

Tags: authentication, devise

I tried to set config.authentication_keys = [:actor_id] in devise.rb, 
here is my form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :serial_number %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :serial_number %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I save name,serial_number and email value in my custom table ,not the devise generated table I also remove default email field. But it still throw out following error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: email
```

I tried to rename email to emails,it throw out following error:

```
undefined method `downcase!' for 1:Fixnum
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your user model:

```
attr_accessible :email
```

Check this Railscast and learn :)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment

Comment: model user does not have this attribute ,I try to remove it.